# XAMPP setup gives wrong mime type for CSS files

Tags: css, .htaccess, xampp

As a junior front-end developer, I've recently been experimenting with MySQL and PHP to hopefully become a full-stack guy one day. I've set up a small server and database. I'm running this through XAMPP, on localhost.

Now this is where things get funny. When I browse my little website, my CSS and JavaScript get loaded, but are completely empty. Let me illustrate that for you:

[The horror of empty sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHq2L.png)

Next to that, I get a warning in my console saying:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/public/css/style.css".

It keeps giving this, even though I defined the type as text/css in my HTML. Now this problem is driving me absolutely crazy for the past two days and I have no idea how to tackle it. Could it be a problem in my folder structure? Do I need to add or change something to my .htaccess file? All help will be greatly appreciated!!

Folder structure

> --App
>
> ------Classes
>
> ------Controllers
>
> ------Models
>
> ------Views
>
> ----------Partials
>
> --Lib
>
> ------Bootstrap
>
> ------NPM
>
> --Public
>
> ------css
>
> ------img
>
> ------js

Comment: Are your file endings correct? Did you change something in the xampp config? Is the CSS sent over PHP?

Comment: do you have an `.htaccess` rerouting everything through index.php? If so, paste it

Comment: Shouldn't it be `localhost/[your-project-name]/public/style.css` ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC (edited question to remove pointless buzzwords)

Comment: @Saad it's whatever he set his vhost config like. both are possible

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel The only thing I changed through XAMPP is the documentroot in the httpd.conf file. My file extensions are correct, as far as I know. I'm referencing the CSS in an HTML header that I require_once with PHP.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Do you mean this:
 "RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]"

Comment: @tereško forgive my ignorance

Comment: put a `die('aaarrrgghh')` on your `index.php` and try and access the css url directly. does it stop on the die? if so, everything is being redirected

Comment: Look at this htaccess. If the file exists in the public folder, it serves it. If not, it goes through inde.php https://github.com/delboy1978uk/bonemvc/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: @delboy1978uk thanks man, you really helped me out. I copied the htaccess example you gave me and, after editing it slightly, things are finally working as I want them to. If you could be so kind and have the knowledge, could you please explain to me what the following htaccesscode actually does?

'>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

>RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]'

Comment: I'll stick it in an answer if you'll mark it the accepted one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds awfully like an `.htaccess` issue.

More than likely, every request is being rewritten to go through `public/index.php`, in a typical Front Controller Pattern.

However, we only want to do that if the files don't actually exist in the public folder.

Here's an `.htaccess` that provides this solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```